# nuxt.js installation: error while create project with command line tool SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to install nuxt.js starter project using nuxt cli

1)Installed vue cli globally `npm install -g vue-cli`

2) Create project with `vue init nuxt-community/starter-template vuetuts`

But i am getting the following error

```
/home/user/.nvm/v0.10.36/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init:35
program.on('--help', () => {
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is called "arrow functions", and is not supported by an ancient (and EOL) version of node like 0.10.

Try upgrading to node 4 or later, and the `vue-cli` package should work fine.